# Karaf OSGI blueprint cm:property-placeholder dows not load from cfg file

Tags: osgi, configuration-files, karaf, blueprint

my blueprint contains:

```
<cm:property-placeholder persistent-id="pool-service" update-strategy="reload">
    <cm:default-properties>
        <cm:property name="maxTotalPerKey" value="2" />
    </cm:default-properties>
</cm:property-placeholder>
```

I placed etc/pool-service.cfg containing maxTotalPerKey=3

when I deploy jar, it picks value 2. If I comment cm:default-properties, it fails with number format exception, so cfg is not read.

Is there anything I am missing (maven dependency, import, configuration,...)?

Thanks,
Viktor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The configuration file cannot contain `-`. Change `etc/PoolService.cfg` file to use:

```
persistent-id="PoolService"
```

Comment: Shouldn't your config file be named the same as the package?
ie package.bundle.version?
It should match the PID?

Comment: well, the persistent-id defines the name of the config file, so it can be named as you wish. the bundle is pool-service.jar

Comment: Unbelievable. After hours spent debugging a similar case (dash in `persistent-id`) in our project, I finally stumbled upon this topic here. Thank you, @ViktorD for sharing this solution!

Anybody blocked by a non-loading configuration - this is probably the case.